# How can I make a package inside of a package in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have tried doing it and making it hierarchical but it just shows the child package and not the parent.

I'm trying to make a project of all of my past school projects and assignments so I want it so look like this

> - School (past)
>
>   - src
>
>     - freshmanYear
>
>       - freshmanYear.src
>
>         - (all of my files)

Comment: By the way don't use `src` as a package name: it brings no value. I'd favor a name that either helps to separate the projects (e.g. `project1`) or create meaningful namespaces (e.g. `gameoflife`, `fizzbuzz`, `fibonacci`).

Comment: Why do you want to aggregate all your projects, by the way? Separated and simple projects, with separated and clear dependencies, may be easier to understand in the future.

Comment: Bc I have all of my assignments that I did this year in one project name as school and each time I would get a new assignment I would create a package and put the class files in there.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on the package and create a new package.  To see it in a `hierarchical` form, left click on the three vertical dots to the right of the package view.  Go down to package representation and select `hierarchical`

Comment: In order to show empty packages as well: click on the Explorer's kebab menu > _Filters and Customization..._ > uncheck _Empty parent packages_

Comment: Yes but when I put it in hierarchical form it only shows the child package; and what is Explorer's kebab menu?

Comment: You can then do flat and have it show the child but it won't be hierarchical.  As far as I know, you cannot do both.

Comment: Ok I found how to do what Emmanuel Chebbi said above; but it still just shows the child package

Comment: Thats dumb ughhh

Comment: But when I create a class file it only sows whether it's in the child or parent package not both

Comment: Ok I played around with it and when I created a class in the parent package it showed it correctly; but when I delete the class in the parent package it just shows the child package.

Comment: Have you unchecked the _Empty parent packages_ filter as advised above (looks like it only works for flat package hierarchy)? BTW, it is okay to only show non-empty child packages: if the explorer only shows an `a.b.c` package it is clear that there are two parent packages `a` and `a.b` that are empty. It also makes the layout more readable.

Comment: Yes I did and it shows it but not in hierarchical; I found a way to do it I just have to have a class in the parent package

Comment: And I have alot and I really don't want to recreate like 40 -50 packages, so do you know how to have a java program create packages for you?

Comment: If all your classes are in Eclipse projects you can move them around by drag'n'drop or right-click > Refactor... > Move. Easy & quick way to move them from your old projects to your new one. That being said, 50 is _a lot_ of packages; make sure the final project remains understandable.

Comment: But when I try to drag n drop it puts it outside the parent package

Comment: Drag'n'dropping a class to a package moves the class to the package. Drag'n'dropping a package to another project moves the package to the project without renaming it; it may then end up outside of the package you dropped it in. I would recommand renaming the package thereafter or write a script to automate it (packages are just folders). If that doesn't solve your problem I would suggest creating a new, dedicated issue because this conversation becomes quite long and differ from the original question.

Comment: So if I were to automate it I could just create a new file (with the appropaite name of course)?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you're saying: what would be the purpose of this file?

Comment: Which one the one that automaates or the projects itself in which I am trying to put packages in?